# Android Tab Swipe

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

This may be a very juvenile question, but this has been driving me insane the last few days.  I currently have an app that has 3 tabs.  I would like to update it so you can swipe left and right to view each tab (as opposed to touching each tab).  I have found a ton of methods on doing this, but I'm still very confused.  I have been told to implement an Action Bar with Tabs as well as fragments, and I have found other sources that use Page Viewers.  Either way this has been a thorn in my side to find something that is what I need.  Is there any good documentation on doing a basic left and right swipe using tabs?  I'm very sorry if this question is repetitive to others.

Answer (score 2):

I really think that a ViewPager (as described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) is what would be best for you.

And yes, it involves fragments.

Comment: I'll give this a look!  I'll let you know how it works out for me, thank you!